# interactivemarker processfeedback callback as a class method

Tags: ros, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I wanted to make a class that contains an interactivemarker server

Something like this http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Interactive%20Markers%3A%20Basic%20Controls

Problem is, I want to do this in a class. Thus I need to set the processFeedback callback as a class method.

I cannot compile the instruction

interactive_markers::InteractiveMarkerServer server->setCallback(int_marker.name, &ClassName::processFeedback);

or

interactive_markers::InteractiveMarkerServer server->setCallback(int_marker.name, &ClassName::processFeedback, this);

A similar issue for ros subscribers and service servers has been solved here
http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Interactive%20Markers%3A%20Basic%20Controls

Does anybody know of something similar for interactivemarker servers?

Thanks

Miguel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/87221/interactivemarker-processfeedback-callback-as-a-class-method/) by [Miguel Riem de Oliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1178/miguel-riem-de-oliveira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 254 on 2013-10-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the answers starting from here

http://answers.ros.org/question/11327/argument-for-subscriberstatuscallback-in-advertise/

... and reading a bit more about boost::bind

the solutions is to do:

interactive_markers::InteractiveMarkerServer
server->setCallback(int_marker.name, boost::bind(&ClassName::processFeedback, this, _1));

regards

Miguel

---

Originally posted by [Miguel Riem de Oliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1178/miguel-riem-de-oliveira/) with karma: 254 on 2013-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on 2015-02-07**:
Thank you so much for this answer!

**Comment by [vkee](https://answers.ros.org/users/21470/vkee/) on 2017-10-10**:
How did you write your callback function? I followed that tutorial but for some reason it is just segfaults when the function is called.